# Applying Barrel Distortion Correction in Java BufferedImage, however getting quite confused result

Tags: java, bufferedimage

guys I'm working on applying Barrel Distortion Correction on images which are projecting from VR headers, the algorithm I used here is something from mipav(https://mipav.cit.nih.gov/pubwiki/index.php/Barrel_Distortion_Correction), they wrapped their data well and you can get quite good result from both their application and ImageMagick.
My original images getting from VR headers is like this.
[projection original images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMbSH.jpg)

and the result of mipav application and ImageMagick with certain parameters is like the following one.
[results of ImageMagic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r12C.jpg)

However, the algorithm part I got from the mipav application got result like this.
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt1C9.jpg)

As you can see, the result is in some condition that looks right in correction but got something strange in its color or image format, can someone help me to figure out the reason??? Many thanks!!!

The following is my code.

```
public class Main2 {

    public BufferedImage readFileAsImage(String fileName) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
        File imageFile = new File(fileName);

        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bufferedImage;
    }

    public Image convertBufferedImageToImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {

        BufferedImage tempCard = bufferedImage.getSubimage( 0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());
        Image card = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempCard, null );
        return card;
    }

    public int[] exportData(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int[] values, int start, int length) {
        if ( (start >= 0) && (length <= values.length)) {

            values = bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(),
                    bufferedImage.getHeight(), values, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth());

        }
        return values;
    }



    public BufferedImage importData(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int[] values) {
        bufferedImage.setRGB(0,0, bufferedImage.getWidth(),
                bufferedImage.getHeight(), values, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth());
        return bufferedImage;

    }

    public void saveBufferedImageAsFile(String fName, BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        File outputfile = new File(fName);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void runAlgorithmn(Image srcImage, BufferedImage srcBufferedImage) {


        int xDim;

        int yDim;

        int sliceSize;

        int i, j;
        int index, index1;
        double ang;

        int[] srcBuffer;
        int[] destBuffer;
        double ySrc;
        double xSrc;
        int imageMin;
        int xBase;
        float delX;
        int yBase;
        float delY;
        int sIndex;
        int cf;
        double xcen;
        double ycen;
        double xoff;
        double yoff;
        double rdest;
        double rdest2;
        double rdest3;
        double rdest4;
        double rsrc;
        double normDist;

        cf = 1;
        xDim = (int) srcImage.getWidth();
        yDim = (int) srcImage.getHeight();
        sliceSize = xDim * yDim;

        BufferedImage destBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(xDim, yDim, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);

        xcen = (xDim - 1.0)/2.0;
        ycen = (yDim - 1.0)/2.0;
        normDist = Math.min(xcen, ycen);

        srcBuffer = new int[cf * sliceSize];
        srcBuffer = exportData(srcBufferedImage, srcBuffer, 0, cf * sliceSize);

        destBuffer = new int[cf * sliceSize];
//        imageMin =  Math.min(srcBufferedImage.getMinX(), srcBufferedImage.getMinY());
//        for (i = 0; i < sliceSize; i++) {
//            destBuffer[i] = imageMin;
//        }

        double a = 0.08;
        double b = -0.28;
        double c = 0.0;
        double d = 1 - a - b - c;

        for (j = 0; j < yDim; j++) {
            index1 = j * xDim;
            yoff = (j - ycen)/normDist;

            for (i = 0; i < xDim; i++) {
                xoff = (i - xcen)/normDist;
                rdest2 = xoff*xoff + yoff*yoff;
                rdest = Math.sqrt(rdest2);
                rdest3 = rdest2 * rdest;
                rdest4 = rdest2 * rdest2;
                rsrc = a * rdest4 + b * rdest3 + c * rdest2 + d * rdest;
                rsrc = normDist * rsrc;
                ang = Math.atan2(yoff,xoff);
                xSrc = xcen + (rsrc * Math.cos(ang));
                ySrc = ycen + (rsrc * Math.sin(ang));

                // Use bilinear interpolation to find the contributions from the
                // 4 nearest neighbors in the original space
                if ((xSrc >= 0.0) && ((xSrc) <= (xDim - 1)) && (ySrc >= 0.0) && (ySrc <= (yDim - 1))) {
                    xBase = (int) Math.floor(xSrc);
                    delX = (float) (xSrc - xBase);
                    yBase = (int) Math.floor(ySrc);
                    delY = (float) (ySrc - yBase);
                    index = index1 + i;
                    sIndex = (yBase * xDim) + xBase;

                    destBuffer[index] = (int) ((1 - delX) * (1 - delY) * srcBuffer[sIndex]);

                    if (xSrc < (xDim - 1)) {
                        destBuffer[index] += (int) (delX * (1 - delY) * srcBuffer[sIndex + 1]);
                    }

                    if (ySrc < (yDim - 1)) {
                        destBuffer[index] += (int) ((1 - delX) * delY * srcBuffer[sIndex + xDim]);
                    }

                    if ((xSrc < (xDim - 1)) && (ySrc < (yDim - 1))) {
                        destBuffer[index] += (int) (delX * delY * srcBuffer[sIndex + xDim + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        importData(destBufferedImage, destBuffer);
        saveBufferedImageAsFile("/Users/pengyuyan/Desktop/singleFrame/images/mytest_result_images/barrel4_result.png", destBufferedImage);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main2 main2 = new Main2();
        BufferedImage srcBufferedImage = main2.readFileAsImage("/Users/pengyuyan/Desktop/singleFrame/images/singleImages/4.png");
        Image srcImage = main2.convertBufferedImageToImage(srcBufferedImage);
        main2.runAlgorithmn(srcImage, srcBufferedImage);

    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail, but the result indicates that you have some overflow in your calculations... Perhaps you need to clamp your values. Also, not sure why you use `TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB`, I think `TYPE_INT_RGB` would be faster as it matches the data returned by `getRGB/setRGB`.

Comment: I've tried every type of buffered image I can try to get the result, only find that doesn't matters.

Comment: The image type matters for the speed/quality of the output only. It's not related to the bug.